How do I remove the "data=" from an API response?
I'm pretty new to this, especially working with APIs. I am working with an API response from a postgres database. When I get the data back, it has a "data=" attached to the front like this:
data=[{'faculty_id': 2, 'first_name': 'Erin',....

I'm trying to place the data into a pandas dataframe, but having that extra bit at the front isn't helping. Any way I can strip off that first bit?
Current code:
response = supabase.table("faculty").select("*").execute()
# print(response)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(response)
df1

What I'm getting back:
    0   1
0   data    [{'faculty_id': 2, 'first_name': 'Erin', 'last...
1   count   None
2   __orig_class__  postgrest.base_request_builder.APIResponse[~_R...


Is that a string? Then just read a tutorial on string manipulation... otherwise we need more clarity. [ask] and [mre]

@Julien It turns out its another object called APIResponse

Use like this:
response = supabase.table("faculty").select("*").execute()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(response[5:])
df1

or
response = supabase.table("faculty").select("*").execute()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(response.data)
df1


Object. Getting error now saying: 'APIResponse' object is not subscriptable

try response.data. I have updated the answer

Works! Thank you!

@AlexSchiff Please check out What should I do when someone answers my question?
